# Fastest batch perspective transform for image augmentation

Tags: pytorch, image-preprocessing, data-augmentation, scipy

I need to do some augmentation for my training images for a neural networks.
The problem is that even when loading batches in parallel, the augmentation is taking longer to perform than the network training.

The problem is in the perspective transforms I'm applying.
Both `cv2.warpPerspective` and `torchvision.transforms.functional.perspective` (with PIL images) are taking roughly the same time.

But both of them do it image by images (which seems very inefficient to me).

So, what are the best (fastest and batch-wise) ways of performing perspective transformation?

- I think of doing it directly with PyTorch functions, but I don't know the algorithm. (Accepting a good algorithm as answer)
- Any other package that can do it faster?

Comment: Are you saying you're performing augmentation manually?

Comment: It's a possibility, as long as it's faster than `cv2`.

Comment: Please note: maintenance > performance. An hour of AI engineer time is worth dozens of hours of GPU rental.

Comment: I meant: are you performing augmentation manually with e.g. opencv instead of existing solutions?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm an independent researcher looking for faster results.

Comment: I doubt you'll get faster than native opencv ;p

Comment: And imagine amount of code and bugs you'll have to get through. Using existing solutions will get you to your goal faster.

Comment: You can always contribute to opencv repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image augmentations heavily relies on your *DataGenerator* and *DataLoader* design, mostly along with the hardware resources that you are using. Apart from that, here is a quick comparison chart to help you with the transformations along with the libraries links.

*The numbers represent the number of images it processes per second*.

[image]

Here are the links to all the required libraries:

1. [Albumentations](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations)
2. [Imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug)
3. [Augmentor](https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor)
4. [SOLT](https://github.com/MIPT-Oulu/solt)

Ref: [Albumentations benchmark results](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/blob/master/README.md#benchmarking-results)

Comment: This might be a very good tool, but if the source code for the perspective transform is here, then it uses `cv2.warpPerspective`, which is the same thing I use. https://github.com/aleju/imgaug/blob/master/imgaug/augmenters/geometric.py

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Could you elaborate on image size and process pipeline you have created? I'll try to look into it.

Comment: Variable image sizes, loop: cv2.open, cv2.resize(256), cv2.warpPerspective, np.array on the list, multiplications, additions, power.